# How can I extend the parameters to add also direction of the rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void RotateDegrees(Vector3 degrees,
        params Animator[] anims)
    {
        Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
        foreach (var anim in anims)
        {
            anim.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(anim.transform.rotation, quaternion, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

For example using this method:

```
RotateDegrees(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), animators[0], animators[1]);
```

But if I want to make that animators[0] will start rotating from right to left and animators[1] from left to right ?
And do it in one line like I'm doing now but with a simple way to decide to what side it will rotate each object.

Comment: When you want to use `params` *(not defined count of arguments)*, you need to make a custom type *(e.g. structure)*, that contain the `Animator` type and also the definition of rotation parameters *(direction, speed, etc.)*. Then process it in the cycle like you do it now for `anims`.

Comment: you are passing in kind of the target Rotation as Vector3 in `degrees` ... so what do you mean by `from right to left` e.g.? `Quaternion.Slerp` uses afaik always the shortest way to rotate to the target rotation...